# Activity not foundException, but i can start it from other Activity

Tags: android

I call Settings activity from 2 different activities in exactly same way. However, when I call it from second activity, I recieve ActivityNotFoundException.

in both activitiece they are called from

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The error

```
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.palsoftware.ebmapps/android.provider.Settings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1767)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1563)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3505)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3466)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3708)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3676)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.palsoftware.ebmapps.StartMonitorActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(StartMonitorActivity.java:97)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2681)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1101)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:494)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:126)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18673)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
06-27 14:42:33.131: E/AndroidRuntime(11763):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Activity is defined in manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.palsoftware.ebmapps.Settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: check package name in class also ?

Comment: make sure you did the correct imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you imported **import android.provider.Settings;** instead of **com.palsoftware.ebmapps.Settings**..

so just import right class and check at once, I hope it will be solved issue.

Comment: nothing.. we just basically posted the same answer at the same time you beat me

Comment: @erik you seems looking genius you will beat at me once..:P

Answer (score 2):

Change `Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);` to `Intent i = new Intent(this, com.palsoftware.ebmapps.Settings.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your settings activity or the android settings.. are both of your classes, importing the same package for Settings?  "/android.provider.Settings"  makes me think that in the one that is not working you accidently imported the wrong "Settings.class"